# Guild Exalted on a level 1 (bank alt)

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a bank alt. She's quite faithful to the auction house, making the trip back and forth to and from the Dwarven District auction house and bank many times a day. She's clad in the hottest attire, and of course, she's got all my money!

She's also level 1.

I'd really like to keep her at level 1, because I think it's most appropriate for a bank alt. This is what I would call a non-negotiable element. Her experience gain is locked so she won't be getting more.

What can I do to get her reputation up with the guild?

I know I can make it half as long by using the Renowned tabard, since my main is exalted, but if I don't have a reliable method, than I'm gaining zero rep twice as fast!

Comment: With the addition of auctioneers in the shrine, this is essentially useless to me. You simply have to be level 5 to be a bank alt so you can get engineering and access the goodies there.

Answer (score 2):

You may be asking for the impossible, but there is a slim set of circumstances that could potentially get you to exalted.

First, [according to Wowpedia](http://www.wowpedia.org/Guild_reputation), these are the things that you can gain guild reputation with:

> - Turning in a green or better quest (awards 166-167 guild experience per quest).
> - Guild group kills on dungeon and raid bosses.
> - Guild group arena and rated battleground wins.
> - Honorable kills (about 1 base reputation per 20 honor points from kills).

Since you're level 1, guild group arena, dungeon, battleground, and raid kills are off the table. That leaves green or better quests and honorable kills.

For the former, [it's slim pickings](http://www.wowhead.com/quests?filter=minrl=1;maxrl=1;si=1;cr=33:2;crs=-2324:1;crv=0:0#0+1+2). When you take out things like world events; quests only available to one faction, race, or class; and so on less than 120 quests available to any one specific person. Questing alone at level 1 is not going to get you to exalted.

So your only option is honorable kills. To be able to farm honorable kills at level 1 requires coordinating with the opposite faction (most likely, two-boxing). It would take an excruciatingly long amount of time to pull off, and there may be some concerns about exploitation<sup>1</sup>, but it should be technically possible to do.

<sup>Note 1: it's against the [Terms of Use](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/legal/wow_tou.html) to "Communicate directly with players who are playing characters aligned with the opposite faction (e.g. Horde communicating with Alliance or vice versa);". Two-boxing characters on separate factions may or may not fit this definition.</sup>

Comment: I'm getting 200 rep for the dailies of Halloween right now. I'm guessing that's +10% for being human and +10% for guild perk.

Comment: @corsiKa that's about right; 167 + 33.4 for +20% rep bonus = 200.4.

Comment: The daily cooking and fishing quests would add a few points, too.

Comment: @JuergenHartelt: [According to Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=26488), the capital city cooking and fishing dailies aren't available until level 10 - meaning those aren't an option for a level 1 character.

Comment: My bad. It is even worse: You need to be level 5 for fishing. It never occurred to me, that the secondary professions could have a level requirement. Sorry for that.